# List item event receiver on lists in multiple webs - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, listitem, splistitem

I have multiple webs instantiated using the same template. When the web is created a custom list is created as well. Is there a way to define a global event receiver to handle to handle the ItemAdded event for all the lists defined with that template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, i don't think this is possible. But you can register your event receiver on the custom list within the template, and all your (newly created lists, obviously) will have the event receiver registered automatically.